# VS 2010 C++ IntelliSense "a storage class may not be specified here" even though it can?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static, intellisense

This is a fairly minor question, but it's annoying me: IntelliSense seems to be convinced that declaring static variables <strike>at the function-scope</strike> in an `if` condition is an error, and complains about it. Only it builds just fine, and even the MSDN docs mention it as a legitimate usage. I'd really like to get rid of the wavy red line, because it comes up fairly often (it's used in a macro I use regularly).

Here's the code, as an example, though it's not the only example in my program:

```
MyForm::MyForm()
{
    _VMESSAGE("Constructing '%s'/%p:%p @ <%p>",GetEditorID(),GetFormType(),formID,this);
    if (static bool runonce = true)
    {
        // patch up vtbl    
        memaddr thisvtbl = (UInt32)memaddr::GetObjectVtbl(this);
        _MESSAGE("Patching MyForm Form vtbl @ <%p>",thisvtbl);
        gLog.Indent();
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Form_NoUseMethods)*0x8; i++)
        {
            if ((Form_NoUseMethods[i/0x20] >> (i%0x20)) & 1)
            {
                thisvtbl.SetVtblEntry(i*4,TESForm_vtbl.GetVtblEntry(i*4));
                _VMESSAGE("Patched Offset 0x%04X",i*4);
            }
        }
        gLog.Outdent();

        runonce  =  false;
    }
}
```

Both the `static` in the `if ( static bool runonce = true )` line and every usage of `_MESSAGE` or `_VMESSAGE` (which uses a similar construct) is underlined by IntelliSense, and hovering over any reads "Error: a storage class may not be specified here." Building the project produces no errors relating to these lines.

Comment: In this case I would trust the IntelliSense!

Comment: @BoPersson: Actually, since IS in VC10 is using the EDG parser, if it disagrees with VC's own compiler, it's almost always right. `:)` (Of course, unless you port your code to other compilers, that doesn't help you much.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The VC++ compiler allows this as a silent extension (it is not legal C++), but the VC++ IntelliSense engine is based on the [EDG compiler frontend](http://www.edg.com/index.php?location=c_frontend), not the VC++ compiler (go figure). So, the IntelliSense error is correct if you're concerned about writing portable code.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it! No concern about portable code here (the whole project is already dependent on VS 2008 or later), and the construct greatly improves the readability and elegance of the macros, so I suppose I'll just have to ignore the wavy lines. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Hold on -- are you saying that the following code compiles and runs in MSVC?

```
int main() {
  if (static bool runonce = true) return 0 ;
}
```

That's a new one on me. g++ certainly [doesn't accept it](http://ideone.com/SF2z5).

BTW, in your question, you mention "declaring static variables at the function-scope", which is not a problem:

```
int main() {
  static bool runonce = true ;
  if (runonce) return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two? The variable declaration should evaluate to the value of the variable after initialization anyway, so declaring it within the `if` doesn't seem like it would matter. Anyway, yes, I am saying that VC++ is accepting `if ( static runonce == true )` as a construct, but IntelliSense does not. It compiles, links, builds, and runs as expected: that block runs once (the first time an instance of `MyForm` is constructed) and no more.

Comment: @David: Lifetime and scope are different things. You can certainly declare a `static` variable inside the *body* of an `if`-statement -- see http://ideone.com/AvF3v. So the explanation must be different.

Comment: you are right, I don't know why I mixed them up in the previous comment (which I am deleting now). At any rate, the set of definitions that can be used in a selection statement is a subset of the things that can be declared in any other scope: storage qualifiers cannot be used, arrays or functions cannot be declared.