# Static function: a storage class may not be specified here

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, static

I have defined a function as static in my class in this manner (snippet of relevant code)

```
#ifndef connectivityClass_H
#define connectivityClass_H

class neighborAtt
{
public:
    neighborAtt(); //default constructor
    neighborAtt(int, int, int);

    ~neighborAtt(); //destructor

    static std::string intToStr(int number);

private:
    int neighborID;
    int attribute1;
    int attribute2;

#endif
```

and in the .cpp file as

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "connectivityClass.h"

static std::string neighborAtt::intToStr(int number)
{
    std::stringstream ss; //create a stringstream
   ss << number; //add number to the stream
   return ss.str(); //return a string with the contents of the stream
}
```

and I get an error (VS C++ 2010) in the .cpp file saying "A storage class may not be specified here" and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

p.s. I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193506/vs-2010-c-intellisense-a-storage-class-may-not-be-specified-here-even-though) which looks like a duplicate but I don't know - as he does - that I am right and the compiler is being finicky. Any help is appreciated, I can't find any information on this!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In the definition in the `.cpp` file, remove the keyword `static`:

```
// No static here (it is not allowed)
std::string neighborAtt::intToStr(int number)
{
    ...
}
```

As long as you have the `static` keyword in the header file, the compiler knows it's a static class method, so you should not and cannot specify it in the definition in the source file.

In C++03, the *storage class specifiers* are the keywords `auto`, `register`, `static`, `extern`, and `mutable`, which tell the compiler how the data is stored.  If you see an error message referring to storage class specifiers, you can be sure it's referring to one of those keywords.

In C++11, the `auto` keyword has a different meaning (it is no longer a storage class specifier).

Comment: Are you sure about `mutable`?  It appears as a *storage-class-specifier* in the BNF, but it doesn't behave as one.  And `thread_local` IS a storage class specifier in C++11.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, C++03 §7.7.1 explicitly lists out those 5 specifiers.